# Ember-Data Destroy model without persisting

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm building a simple search interface where each new search removes previous results and pushes new ones into the store. So before making a new query and pushing new records into store I remove the previous ones using `deleteRecord()`. However, EmberData won't push new results while there are uncommitted records raising this exception:

`Attempted to handle event`pushedData`on <App.SearchResult:ember555:312> while in state root.deleted.uncommitted`

The problem is that I simply want to remove the existing results (without persisting the removal of course) and show new results.

Comment: Are the previous results saved to the backend?

Comment: @jcbvm no, they are just for display to the user and should be removed on the frontend only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, you only use them at the frontend, in that case you could use the function `unloadRecord` to delete the records. This function will immediately remove the record from the store where `deleteRecord` will only mark it for removal (and will be removed when you save the record to the backend).

See [unloadRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_unloadRecord)

Comment: yep, does exactly what I need!